# Text field not populating from the user previously entered value in Laravel form

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, laravel-6

I'm having an user registration form in my register blade. There when I entered the relevant values and press submit button the values will be validated from the controller and take the action accordingly,(saving values or redirecting user back to register form)

**The Problem:**

If the user has violated my registration rules, user will be re directed to the registration form. At there I want to populate the text fields in the form by user's previously entered values. Now the problem is all the values get populated properly except the email address field...

My Code for the form as follows,

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.First Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}"   autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="last_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.Last Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="last_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('last_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="last_name" value="{{ old('last_name') }}"  autofocus>

                                @error('last_name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="moblie" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Mobile') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="mobile_1" type="tel" class="form-control @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror" name="mobile" value="{{ old('mobile') }}" style="min-width: 330px;"  autofocus>
                                    @error('mobile')
                                    <br/>
                                        <span class="help-block" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>

                                    @enderror

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.Username') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}"  autofocus>

                                @error('username')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" >

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" >
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default subscribe px-5">
                                    {{ __('sentence.Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And my registration function as follows,

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'confirmed','regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{12,}$/'],
            'mobile'=>['required','numeric','min:9','regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
            2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
            4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],
            'username'=>['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:10', 'unique:users'],    
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'mobile'=>$data['mobile'],
            'username'=>$data['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'propic'=>'hello-user.png',
        ]);
    }
```

**Summary:**

Email field not get populated from the previously entered user input.

**NOTE:**

I have used email input type as TEXT due to avoid bootstrap validations.

Comment: I can't find your error but I found other errors. Are you sure you are testing the register page and not the login page? Your 'mobile' regex is insane and could be messing your code. Did you try without it? In your create method, you have 'last_name' twice. Your html looks correct but you shouldn't use autofocus on every input.

Comment: noted those mistakes, fixed and tried again, but still having the issue

Comment: It should work. Did you try removing the 'mobile' regex to see if it's causing the problem?

Comment: yes tried, still the issue was there

Comment: Do you have a value for 'email' in the $data array before validation? Add this before Validator to check: `dd($data);` If yes, you problem is in the HTML (run your code through W3C Validator), if no your problem is in your controller. Also, make sure you don't confuse the register and the login page, they look very similar.